# how can I run javaw in windows XP cmd?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, windows-xp, javaw

I made a program using JAVA.

I export the java project as runnable jar file.

I tested it in Windows 7 32bit.

It runs perfectly.

However, when I tested it in windows xp 32bit(I'm not sure about it's SP version. maybe SP2 or SP3)

It shows error message "cannot access to C:\my.jar"

I did googling, and found that

***Windows 7 and XP have different function to load javaw***

However... I don't know the exact way to run javaw in Windows XP

How can I run it?

Here is the **code** with **"Cannot access"** error

```
public void RunApplication() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -jar " + PROGRAM_PATH + "/Client.jar");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is another code.

If I run this, Windows XP doens't show anything.
**No error, No application.**

```
public void RunApplication() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start javaw -jar " + PROGRAM_PATH + "/Client.jar");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of java have you used?

Comment: I use java1.4 ... I want to throw this terrible version and use 1.8, but I can't...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/644565/windows-xp-can-run-jar-from-cmd-prompt-but-batch-file-errors-on-cannot-acces

Comment: **is** `my.jar` in your ``c:\``?

Comment: I'll try to read the link. Thanks Bogdan M. :)

Comment: Yes. my jar file's path is C:/Applicatioin/Client.jar